# XPath multiple request

Tags: xpath, selenium, selector

I'm trying to use such XPath expression to choose SOME NUMERICAL element from the heap: `//input[contains(@name, '[options]')][2]`

Well, it's won't work. What do I want is to take some input element on the page, which contains '[options]' string in the 'name' attribute, and I want to choose second one.

For example, I have 3 'name' elements on the page, and all of them had this '[options]' value, so I want to take the only one of them by his number. Just like you can take, for example, second //input[2] on the page.

Comment: what is the environment? java? firefox plugin?

Comment: Firefox plugin, Selenium IDE. Selenese itself.

Comment: So, thanks to @Arran. The solution is simple:

type | xpath=(//input[contains(@name, '[options]')])[2] | ${value}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(//input[contains(@name, '[options]')])[2]
```

is what you are after.

Comment: Thx, I think that is right solution. Unfortunately it's won't work for me in selenium IDE, because the string have to begin like "//" in order to launch xpath processor.

Comment: I thought you could get round this by putting "xpath=" before it, that way it'll work regardless of if it starts with "//"? Can you try that?